# C# Spire.Xls definir lista de workbooks

Tags: c#, .net

Como eu posso criar uma lista de workbooks

Exemplo de workbooks criados para adicionar a lista:

```
        private static void Merge()
        { 
            Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
            workbook.LoadFromFile(@"merge1.xlsx");

            Workbook workbook2 = new Workbook();
            workbook2.LoadFromFile(@"merge2.xlsx");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode crer uma lista da seguinte forma:

Usando o *namespace* `System.Collections.Generic` tem o `List<>`, nele é possível definir uma lista de algum tipo, no seu caso `Workbook`. Por fim, para adicionar itens na lista use o `Add()`

obs: Modifiquei o método para retornar a lista.

```
private static List<Workbook> Merge()
{
    List<Workbook> workbooks = new List<Workbook>();

    Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
    workbook.LoadFromFile(@"merge1.xlsx");
    workbooks.Add(workbook);

    Workbook workbook2 = new Workbook();
    workbook2.LoadFromFile(@"merge2.xlsx");
    workbooks.Add(workbook2);

    return workbooks;
}
```